# Render.com error with form POST to Supabase

Tags: flask, supabase, render.com

Commented code below. App.py file:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify, redirect, url_for, flash
from pydantic import BaseModel, EmailStr
import os
from supabase import create_client, Client
import smtplib


# Define the send_email function
def send_email(subject, body, recipient_email):
    # Set up the email server
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.ehlo()
    # Log in to the email account
    server.login(os.environ.get("SENDER_EMAIL"), os.environ.get("SENDER_EMAIL_PASSWORD"))
    # Compose the email message
    message = f"Subject: {subject}\n\n{body}"
    # Send the email
    server.sendmail("sender_email@example.com", recipient_email, message)
    # Close the connection to the email server
    server.quit()

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = os.environ.get("SECRET_KEY")

# Initialize Supabase client
url: str = os.environ.get("SUPABASE_URL")
key: str = os.environ.get("SUPABASE_KEY")
supabase: Client = create_client(url, key)

class ContactForm(BaseModel):
    name: str
    email: EmailStr

@app.route("/", methods=["GET"])
def index():
    
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/contact", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def submit_contact_form():
    if request.method == "POST":
        # Get user input from the form
        full_name = request.form.get("full-name")
        email = request.form.get("email")
        # Validate user input
        if not full_name or not email:
            flash("Name and email need to be filled", "warning")
        else:
            # Insert a new row into the 'contacts' table in the database
            response, error = supabase.table('contacts').insert({'name': full_name, 'email': email}).execute()

             # Send an email to the user
            subject = "Thank you for your message!"
            body = f"Dear {full_name},\n\nThank you for contacting us. We have received your message and will get back to you shortly.\n\nBest regards,\nThe XYZ team"
            send_email(subject, body, email)

            flash("Thanks for you message. We will be in touch!", "success")
            # Return a success message to the user
            return redirect(url_for("index"))
    # For GET requests, return the index template
    return render_template("index.html")
    return 'OK'

@app.route("/email-contact", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def submit_email_form():
    if request.method == "POST":
        # Get user input from the form
        email = request.form.get("email")
        # Validate user input
        if not email:
            flash("Name and email need to be filled", "warning")
        else:
            # Insert a new row into the 'contacts' table in the database
            response, error = supabase.table('contacts_email_only').insert({'email': email}).execute()
             # Send an email to the user
            subject = "Thank you for your message!"
            body = f"Hi there,\n\nThank you for contacting us. We have received your message and will get back to you shortly.\n\nBest regards,\nThe AI team"
            send_email(subject, body, email)

            flash("Thanks for you message. We will be in touch!", "success")
            # Return a success message to the user
            return redirect(url_for("index"))
    # For GET requests, return the index template
    return render_template("index.html")
    return 'OK'
```

index.html:

```
  <form action="/contact" method="POST" class="cta-form" id="contact-form">
                    <label for="full-name">Full Name</label>
                    <input id="full-name" type="text" placeholder="John Smith" name="full-name" id="" required>
                    <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                    <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="me@example.com"name="email" id="" required>
                    <button class="btn">Lets go</button>
                </form>
```

Render.com logs

```
May 2 04:37:29 PM  Traceback (most recent call last):
May 2 04:37:29 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/httpx/_transports/default.py", line 60, in map_httpcore_exceptions
May 2 04:37:29 PM      yield
May 2 04:37:29 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/httpx/_transports/default.py", line 218, in handle_request
May 2 04:37:29 PM      resp = self._pool.handle_request(req)
May 2 04:37:29 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/httpcore/_sync/connection_pool.py", line 209, in handle_request
May 2 04:37:29 PM      "Request URL is missing an 'http://' or 'https://' protocol."
May 2 04:37:29 PM  httpcore.UnsupportedProtocol: Request URL is missing an 'http://' or 'https://' protocol.
May 2 04:37:29 PM  
May 2 04:37:29 PM  The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
May 2 04:37:29 PM  
May 2 04:37:29 PM  Traceback (most recent call last):
May 2 04:37:29 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2529, in wsgi_app
May 2 04:37:29 PM      response = self.full_dispatch_request()
May 2 04:37:29 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1825, in full_dispatch_request
May 2 04:37:29 PM      rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
May 2 04:37:29 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1823, in full_dispatch_request
May 2 04:37:29 PM      rv = self.dispatch_request()
May 2 04:37:29 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
May 2 04:37:29 PM      return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
May 2 04:37:29 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/app.py", line 75, in submit_email_form
May 2 04:37:29 PM      response, error = supabase.table('contacts_email_only').insert({'email': email}).execute()
May 2 04:37:29 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/postgrest/_sync/request_builder.py", line 59, in execute
May 2 04:37:29 PM      headers=self.headers,
May 2 04:37:29 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 821, in request
May 2 04:37:29 PM      return self.send(request, auth=auth, follow_redirects=follow_redirects)
May 2 04:37:29 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 912, in send
May 2 04:37:29 PM      history=[],
May 2 04:37:29 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 939, in _send_handling_auth
May 2 04:37:29 PM      history=history,
May 2 04:37:29 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 973, in _send_handling_redirects
May 2 04:37:29 PM      response = self._send_single_request(request)
May 2 04:37:29 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 1009, in _send_single_request
May 2 04:37:29 PM      response = transport.handle_request(request)
May 2 04:37:29 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/httpx/_transports/default.py", line 218, in handle_request
May 2 04:37:29 PM      resp = self._pool.handle_request(req)
May 2 04:37:29 PM    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/contextlib.py", line 130, in __exit__
May 2 04:37:29 PM      self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
May 2 04:37:29 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/httpx/_transports/default.py", line 77, in map_httpcore_exceptions
May 2 04:37:29 PM      raise mapped_exc(message) from exc
May 2 04:37:29 PM  httpx.UnsupportedProtocol: Request URL is missing an 'http://' or 'https://' protocol.
```

Regarding the error => Request URL is missing an 'http://' or 'https://' protocol, I have checked the .flaskenv file and my SUPABASE_URL is "https://......". The app works perfectly locallly and posts to Supabase successfully so cant figure out what is going wrong!

Comment: Figured this out! When filling in Environment variable values on Render - I enclosed in inverted commas. Do not do this. Removed them and form records are now posted to Supabase as expected.